# Joining values from a DataFrame row with comma being separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My *DataFrame* row `line = fd.iloc[0]` is:

```
id                         31458598
total_matched             104671.25
market           Under 3.5 Goals FT
one                               0
two                               0
three                             0
four                              0
five                              0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I have join this values with comma, like this:

```
f"{line['id']},{line['total_matched']},{line['market']},{line['one']},{line['two']},{line['three']},{line['four']},{line['five']}\n"
```

But this method is archaic, so I tried to use join:

```
','.join(line) + '\n'
```

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found
```

```
line.join(',') + '\n'
```

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

What is the correct way to join these values with a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) after ensuring you have strings:

```
line.astype(str).str.cat(sep=',')
```

output: `'31458598,104671.25,Under 3.5 Goals FT,0,0,0,0,0,0'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to combine all of your columns into a single column

```
df['Combo'] = df[[x for x in df.columns]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis = 1)
```

You can add this if statement if you would like to remove any of the columns in your for loop

```
df['Combo'] = df[[x for x in df.columns if x != column_to_exclude]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis = 1)
```